# SQL Union with fixed number of rows as result

Tags: sql

This is a simple representation of my student table.

| Student | Year | Class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2010 | A |
| 2 | 2010 | A |
| 3 | 2010 | C |
| 4 | 2010 | B |
| 5 | 2011 | B |
| 6 | 2012 | B |

I want to compose a random group of 5 students.
In the group there will be 2 students of year 2010 and 3 students of group B. These values are user specified.

A simple union doesn't always work, because of the duplicate values. Sometimes there are 4 students, sometimes there are 5 students. I always want 5 records.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 2 * FROM [Student] WHERE YEAR = 2010 ORDER BY NEWID()) A
UNION 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 3 * FROM [Student] WHERE Class = 'B' ORDER BY NEWID()) B
```

Is this possible with a SQL query?

Comment: `WHERE YEAR = 2010 AND Class <> 'B'` and vice versa

Comment: if you have for example 2 common rows, this would lead to 3 unique rows: how do you decide how many row from each query you would finally retrieve?

Comment: you'll need to order all your rows without taking into account the final number of rows you need, then use for example `limit 5` statement